# Login Function in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to rapid development frameworks and I am currently working on a project on Cakephp. I have been having a problem establishing a session on my application.
I have used the login function but it won't accept the credentials I put in and returns the flash message for incorrect credentials. I have tried changing the function in different ways but it's clear that it is not establishing a session. Please help.

Here is the relevant code.

UsersController.php

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ( $this->request->is( 'post' ) ) {
            if ( $this->Auth->login() ) {
               $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
               $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppController.php

```
public $components = array('Session', 'Auth');
```

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me as being incorrect with your code.  I'd turn on debug and get a mysql dump to see the actual query it's using to login.

Comment: This is the querry SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`typeid`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`fname`, `User`.`mname`, `User`.`lname`, `User`.`photo`, `User`.`gender`, `User`.`bio`, `User`.`dob`, `User`.`reel`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `mdbk`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`username` = 'crystals' LIMIT 1

Comment: Are you sure that's the query for logging in?  It's not comparing with the password field.  So either it's the wrong query, or there's something else wrong, though the problem is not in the code you've posted.

Comment: How can I debug that?

Comment: I'd start by looking at your Auth component's settings.  If nothing jumps out as  being wrong, then start examining the CakePHP library to see if you can figure out where is the code that makes it compare passwords, and why it isn't getting there.  I normally just temporarily add tons of calls to `debug()` on various variables to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your AppController is missing some information inside `$components`.
Try this:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Cookie',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => '**YOUR CONTOLLERr**',
            'action' => '**YOUR ACTION**'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => '**YOUR CONTOLLERr**',
            'action' => '**YOUR ACTION**',
            'home'
        ),
        'loginAction' => array(
        'controller' => '**YOUR CONTOLLERr**',
        'action' => '**YOUR ACTION**'
        ),
        'authError' => 'Access Denied!',
        'loginError' => 'Invalid user and password',
        'authorize' => array('Controller'),
        'authenticate' => array('Form' => array(
                                'userModel' => 'User',
                                'fields' => array(
                                    'username' => '**LOGIN FIELD**',
                                    'password' => '**PASSWORD FIELD**'
                                    )
                                )
        ),
    )
);
}
```

It is important to set `Session` inside AppController so you can establish it.
Also its important to check **PasswordHash** since Cakephp only validate credentials if password stored in Database is Hashed.

Hope It helps you.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the feedback. I had set the Session, I have just modified my $components method to the code you have provided but the result is still the same. What could be lacking?

Comment: You need to adjust **loginRedirect** , **logoutRedirect** and **loginAction** according to your application. But why are you validating submit form twice with `if ($this->request->is('post')) {` ?  Besides, include this line in your Userscontroller.php and check if it works: `App::uses('CakeSession','Model/Datasource');`

Answer (score 0):

I can see nothing in your "relevant code", you can compare the data of that you obtain with your DB in your login, just use debug, so:

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            debug($this->request->data);
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {
                //$this->Session->setFlash(('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
            }
        }
      }
```

with this we can obtain more information you can tell me what show and if those data is the same in the DB.

Comment: Hey this is the result I get           array(
 'User' => array(
  'password' => '*****',
  'username' => 'test'
 )
)

Comment: Give a debug the password and compare if it's the same as in the database

Comment: I do not know how to do that. Let me try though. Thank you.